# Unpacking Asprotect SKE 2.1

Tags: unpacking, patch-reversing

Since AsProtect is pretty dated, I was wondering if there is any tools out there that can do the unpacking for the user. If not, I guess manual is the way to go.

In case of manual mode, I would love it if you could point some papers.

Answer (score 1):

For this packer, I have successfully used this script by VolX: [ASProtect 1.3x - 2.xx Unpacker v1.15F](https://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.3519).  You still need an external tool for the IAT reconstruction (I mostly use Scylla), but the script provides all the parameters required.